# Is it possible to create a class that can only be instanced as member of another class, but still be publicly accessible through this in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop

I have a custom applicationdata class in this I would like to categorize its data through member subclasses e.g. a userdata class. However the userdata class should not be able to be instantiated other places than in the applicationdata class, but still be accessible through the applicationdata class. Is this possible.

To illustrate I want to be able to access the class like this: 
ApplicationData.UserData.SomeProperty

However outside the ApplicationData class it should not be possible to instance like this:
Dim ud as new UserData

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class ApplicationData
{
    private UserData user = new UserData();

    public UserData User
    {
        get
        {
            return user;
        }
    }

    public class UserData
    {
        internal UserData()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

It's not exactly what you describe, in that it's still possible to create a UserData instance outside of your ApplicationData class - but only within the same assembly. Note also that you have to name the class (UserData) differently from the property you're exposing (User).

Rather than nest the class like this, the approach I would take instead would be to have a public IUserData interface, and an internal UserData class. Your ApplicationData class can then expose a UserData property of type IUserData.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would tackle this is as follows:
Write a public interface IUserData
Make the UserData implement the interface IUserData and make this class private
ApplicationData would expose the class through a property named UserData of type IUserData

Comment: yes in this case, MEF(Managed Extensibility Framework) can be used. But if i get abstract class, why would i go for a longer line of code! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can define user data as a abstract class so that it can only be inherited, can not be instanced. For more information see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k535acbf%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Now if UserData and ApplicationData reside in the same assembly, you can user **'internal'** keyword. When you use internal keyword to the class, that class in only accessible in the same assembly. The classes which are outside the assembly can not access it. For more information see this [link.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Cheerss!

Answer (score 0):

Just use an internal constructor.

No one outside the assembly will be able to create instances.